# Rails 5.2 associations and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models Owner, Pet:

- Owner :has_many :pets
- Pet :belongs_to :owner.

Very standard. In the routes I have

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :owners do
    resources :pets
  end
end
```

And in the form where I am creating or updating a Pet, I need to also include the Owner. I have tried various ways of doing it:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@owner, pet], local: true) do |form| %>
<%= form_with(url: [@owner, pet], local: true) do |form| %>
<%= form_with(model: @owner, url: [@owner, pet], local: true) do |form| %>
```

And in each case the owner_id ends up at the wrong 'level':

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"sDU1E/rdnRbl/7iXwWSo1mV4ABqgrdIl0HylmLSKvrnEzPUsU+seHaDZeFuZVb6MdBfVNHR7Wgzqmv/7XgMNGQ==", 
 "pet"=>{"name"=>"King Smith", "age"=>"12", "breed"=>"Foo"}, 
 "commit"=>"Create Pet", "owner_id"=>"2"}
```

I thought, pre-5.2, the first approach was correct. Can you see where I am going wrong?

Comment: `owner_id` is not at the wrong level, or do you want to update the owner_id of the pet? the way it is now you can do `Owner.find(params[:owner_id]).pets.create(pet_params)` which seems right to me.

Comment: I was trying to get it all to go through strong_params, but now that you mention it, I am not sure why that would be any better. If I am creating a new pet, then of course I do want to do that, but what you write there will correctly initialize the owner_id anyway.

Comment: If you really need the owner_id inside params[:pet] you can have a hidden_field on the form, but I don't think you really need that either and it can have a security risk: someone could change the owner_id inside the form fields and set his own pet to another owner if you allow it as a permited attribute!

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `local: true` option in [form_with](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with), the form is submitted through a regular POST-request, not XHR. So why not to use [form_for](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) instead:

```
<%= form_for [@owner, @pet] do |form| %>
```

For `form_with` the syntax will be:

```
<%= form_with(model: [@owner, @pet], local: true) do |form| %>
```

Please note using of instance variable `@pet` instead of local `pet` as in your question. `@pet` should be initialized in the controller, for example, in `new` action, as

```
 @pet = @owner.pets.build
```

and when processed in `create` action:

```
 @pet = @owner.pets.build(pet_params)
 if (@pet.save)
   ...
```

Also, I would not care about "level" of your `owner_id` param, because of [nested resources](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources). `pets` resource is nested inside of `owners`. When submitting a form with a new pet the POST request is sent to URL which looks something like `/owners/OWNER_ID/pets` (which is defined by the form helper, `form_for` or `form_with`, in examples above). Rails router will match this request, call action `create` of `PetsController` and set `params[:owner_id]` to `OWNER_ID`. So it goes not from your form data but set by the router.

Comment: I think he can use `@owner.pet` on the second part, there is no need to create `@pet` too

Comment: Can’t agree. Also `@owner` has no method `pet` in case of `has_many` relationship.